# AJAX call only calls data for one dropdown list instead of two dropdown lists

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am new and still learning on AJAX call and I cant figure out why my AJAX call only calls data for one dropdown list only. Okay, the scenario is that I have 3 dropdown list in my form which are to select a doctor, display consultation fee and provide list of appointment date. The problem I'm facing is that when a doctor is selected in the `doctor dropdown list`, the AJAX call will  only loads the data for the `appointment date dropdown list`. It didn't load the consultation fee.

Here are my code for doctor, consultation fee and appointment date dropdown list:

```
<div>
  <label>Select Doctor</label>
  <select name="doctor" id="get_doctor_name" onchange="getfee()" autocomplete="off" required>
    <option hidden value="">Select Doctor</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div>
  <label>Consultation Fee</label>
  <select name="fees" id="get_doctor_fee" autocomplete="off" readonly>
  </select>
</div>

<div>
  <label>Appointment Date</label>
  <select name="appdate" id="get_date">
  </select>
</div>
```

**UPDATED:** Here are the script for the AJAX call with function `getfee()` and `getdate()`:

```
<script>
      //function for fee details
      function getfee() 
      {
        $("#loaderIcon").show();
        jQuery.ajax(
        {
          url: "getfee.php",
          data: {doctor : $("#get_doctor_name").val()},
          type: "POST",
          success: function(data) 
          {
            $("#get_doctor_fee").html(data);
            $("#loaderIcon").hide();
          },
          error: function() {}
        });
      }

      //function for appointment date details
       function getdate() {
       $("#loaderIcon").show();
       jQuery.ajax({
       url: "getslot-date.php",
       data: {doctor : $("#get_doctor_name").val()},
       type: "POST",
       success: function(data) {
         $("#get_date").html(data);
        $("#loaderIcon").hide();
       },
       error: function() {}
    });
 }
    </script>
```

Here are code in `getfee.php` in the AJAX call script:

```
<?php
include('incl/connection.php');
if(!empty($_POST['doctor'])) 
{
    $doctor =$_POST['doctor'];

    $sql = "SELECT D_FEES FROM tbldoctor 
            WHERE D_ID=:doctor";

    $query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $query->bindParam(':doctor',$doctor,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->execute();
    if (!$query->execute()) {
    print_r($query->errorInfo());
}
    $results=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $cnt=1;
    if($query->rowCount() > 0) 
    {
        foreach($results as $results) 
            { 
               echo '<option readonly value="'.htmlentities($results->D_FEES).'">'. htmlentities($results->D_FEES).'</option>';
            }
    }
    else
    {
       echo '<option value=""> No Doctor in this specilization</option>';
       echo "<script>$('#submit').prop('disabled',true);</script>"; 
    }
}
?>
```

Here are code in `getslot-date.php` in the AJAX call script:

```
<?php
include('incl/connection.php');
if(!empty($_POST['doctor'])) 
{
    $doctor =$_POST['doctor'];
    $sql = "SELECT T_ID, T_DATE, T_TIME FROM tbltimeslot 
            WHERE D_ID=:doctor AND A_ID IS NULL";

    $query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $query->bindParam(':doctor',$doctor,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->execute();
    if (!$query->execute()) {
    print_r($query->errorInfo());}
    $results=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $cnt=1;
    if($query->rowCount() > 0) 
    {
        foreach($results as $results) 
        {
            echo '<option value="'.htmlentities($results->T_ID).'">'.htmlentities($results->T_DATE).' @ '.htmlentities($results->T_TIME).'</option>';
        }
    }
    else
    {
       echo '<option value=""> No available date</option>';
       echo "<script>$('#submit').prop('disabled',true);</script>"; 
    }
}
?>
```

And below are the table for `tbldoctor` and `tbltimeslot`:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbldoctor` (
  `D_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `D_SPECILIZATION` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `D_NAME` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `D_FEES` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE `tbltimeslot` (
  `T_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `T_DATE` date NOT NULL,
  `T_TIME` time NOT NULL,
  `D_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `A_ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
)
```

Comment: Looks like just a typo.  You have two functions called `getfee`, so one overwrites the other.  Either put both your operations in one function or give your functions different names.

Comment: Just rename one of the two functions so you can know which one you are calling.

Comment: Like this @MahmoudMostafa @David? `<select class="form-control" name="doctor" id="get_doctor_name" onchange="getfee()" onchange="getdate()" autocomplete="off" required>` . I tried to run the code but now, the dropdown list for date isn't showing any data

Comment: fyi, when hitting your `else` branch ... I'm not sure if a `<script>` is being executed inside a `<select>`

Comment: Don't use two `onchange` in your HTML. What the comments were trying to say: in your javascript there are two `function getfee() {`, rename the second to something like `function getdate() {`. Also read up on how `data` [should be passed](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) (basically Mohammad Taghizad Badrian's answer)

Comment: Oh I see.. So how do I call the function `getdate()` without using the `onchange` then? Also, thank you for the link you've provided. I am trying to digest its contents hehe

Answer (score 0):

you should return your data as json and then use it

```
$results=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
// remove all code after it, and add the following line
echo json_encode($results);
```

and in your ajax render options like this

```
function getfee() 
      {

        $.ajax(
        {
          url: "getfee.php",
          data: {doctor : $("#get_doctor_name").val()},
          type: "POST",
          beforeSend: function() {
          //start loader
             $("#loaderIcon").show();
          },
          error: function() {  // hide loader when error otherwise will stuck on your screen
          $("#loaderIcon").hide();}
          success: function(objJson) 
          {
            var data = $.parseJSON(objJson);
            console.log(data); // to view how it looks in console, array, empty or whatever
            $('#get_doctor_fee').empty();
            if(data.length > 0) {
              $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                $('#get_doctor_fee').append('<option value="'+ value.D_FEES+'">'+ value.D_FEES +'</option>');
              });
            } else {
                $('#get_doctor_fee').append('<option value="">No Doctor in this specilization </option>');
                $('#submit').prop('disabled',true);
            }
            $("#loaderIcon").hide();
          },
        });
      }
```

you can apply the same adjustment for other dropdown, its just a sample to show you how to manage it.

and one more thing you can change is calling your functions, this way functions can be more customizable and have more control., but its upto how you like

```
$('#get_doctor_name').on('change', function() {
    // call your ajax here
      ...
      url: "getfee.php",
      data: {doctor : $(this).val()},
      type: "POST",
      ...
      // update get_doctor_fee here
})

$('#get_doctor_fee').on('change', function() {
    // call your ajax here
      ...
      url: "getslot-date.php",
      data: {doctor : $(this).val()},
      type: "POST",
      ... 
      // update get_date dropdown
})
```

Answer (score -2):

you Must write data Like This

```
function getfee() {
       $("#loaderIcon").show();
       jQuery.ajax({
       url: "getslot-date.php",
       data: {doctor : $("#get_doctor_name").val()},
       type: "POST",
       success: function(data) {
         $("#get_date").html(data);
        $("#loaderIcon").hide();
       },
       error: function() {}
    });
 }
```

Comment: Like what? What did you change and why?

Comment: data: {doctor : $("#get_doctor_name").val()}

Comment: I tried to create another function `onchange="getdate()"` and placed it beside `onchange="getfee()"`. So now my code looks like this `<select class="form-control" name="doctor" id="get_doctor_name" onchange="getfee()" onchange="getdate()" autocomplete="off" required>` . I also renamed the function in the script with id `get_date` from `getfee()` to `getdate()` . And now the date dropdown list is not showing any data.

Comment: please write complete Code In another answer i can read it and answer